# php array declaration inside loop

Tags: php

```
$arr = array();
while($row1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $case_code = $row1['case_code'];
    $arr[$case_code]['type1'] += $row1['type1'];
    $arr[$case_code]['type2'] += $row1['type2'];
    .................
}
```

I am getting notice undefined offset, undefined index.
Should i use

```
if (!isset($arr[$case_code])) {
    $arr[$case_code] = ''
}
if (!isset($arr[$case_code]['type1'])) {
    $arr[$case_code]['type1'] = 0;
}
if (!isset($arr[$case_code]['type2'])) {
    $arr[$case_code]['type1'] = 0;
}
```

Or is there any other better way to do this.

Comment: set it first before using it, like: `$arr[$case_code] = array()`

Comment: for me i don't mind having an initialization of `type1, type2`, unless its that many, then you should have placed it in another table instead

Comment: `$arr[$case_code] = ''` should be `$arr[$case_code] = array();`

Comment: or maybe just dedicate a separate query for it, like using `SUM` grouped it by, then no need to do those things

Comment: You are defining `$arr` as an array but not `$arr[$case_code]` as an array. Since you want to fill both they both need to be defined as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it first to an array (because it seems you want to use it as an array.) then you can use it.

```
$arr = array();
while($row1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $case_code = $row1['case_code'];

    if (!isset($arr[$case_code])) { // check if the index was already set
        $arr[$case_code] = array('type1' => 0, 'type2' => 0, ..., 'typeN' => 0); // set it first
    } 
    $arr[$case_code]['type1'] += $row1['type1'];
    $arr[$case_code]['type2'] += $row1['type2'];
    .................
}
```